# Campaign Monitor/Magento: How to to add new subscribers to the subscribers list

Tags: magento-1.7

I'm using the fontis magento/campaign monitor extension; installation all OK, apart from new subscribers are being added to directly to the unsubscribe list rather than the subscriber list. I'm using my CM API Key (the client key doesn't seem to work) and the API list ID for the client's list.  Any thoughts as to where I've gone wrong.